# Temporarily Suspend scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a large amount of code in `scrollViewDidScroll` in a `scrollView` with paging enabled and I also have a button that resets the view to `0, 0`. I need to temporarily suspend `scrollViewDidScroll` for the duration of the animated reset, as the animation is "scrolling" constantly. Is there a way to suspend it at the beginning of the reset and then reinstate it after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a BOOL instance variable to your class, for example shouldSkipScrollCode and check it inside scrollViewDidScroll. If it is YES, just return - otherwise, execute your code. When the user presses the button to reset the scrollview, set this variable to YES.

To re-set it to NO, use the delegate notification [scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html), which will fire when the scroll is complete. This is where you have an opportunity to reset shouldSkipScrollCode back to NO.